# How to send messages to specific session in Spring through Websockets (STOMP) while multiple connections are open with same user?

Tags: java, spring, websocket, stomp, spring-websocket

I can configure sending messages to specific users with WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer and SimpleMessageBroker, it works well.

Problem:
When somebody subscribes on specific userId, I want to send the previous messages from db to that subscriber. But if there already exists a connection and subscription with same userId (e.g. user logs in from another device/browser), old subscriber will receive the initial messages from db too. And with every new subscriber with the same userId, older subscribers will receive the same messages.

So how to send the initial messages from db to specific session, not all sessions?
Is this even possible with STOMP protocol?

Here is the code:

```
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/stomp/message").setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/chatroom", "/user");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        registry.setUserDestinationPrefix("/user");
    }
}

public class MessageController {

    @MessageMapping("/private-message")
    private void receivePrivateMessage(
            @Payload Message message,
            Principal user,
            @Header("simpSessionId") String sessionId) {
        log.info("server received private message: " + message);
        simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(message.getReceiverId().toString(), "/private-message",       message);
    }
}

public class EventSubscribeListener implements ApplicationListener<SessionSubscribeEvent> {

    private final SimpMessagingTemplate simpMessagingTemplate;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(SessionSubscribeEvent event) {
        log.info("Stomp subscribed");
        
        TODO get messages from db and send initial messages from db to to specific session/subscriber
    }
}
```

Only idea I had is that I could replace the userId based subscribing to sessionId based subscribing. But that would mean frontend has to get the sessionId and subscribe with it. I don't want FE to deal with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`@SubscribeMapping`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/websocket/stomp/handle-annotations.html#websocket-stomp-subscribe-mapping):

> @SubscribeMapping is similar to @MessageMapping but narrows the mapping to subscription messages only. It supports the same method arguments as @MessageMapping. **However for the return value, by default, a message is sent directly to the client** (through clientOutboundChannel, in response to the subscription) and not to the broker (through brokerChannel, as a broadcast to matching subscriptions). Adding @SendTo or @SendToUser overrides this behavior and sends to the broker instead.